# How does this link execute javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to reverse engineer a web page sorta. I have access to the source code but it is thousands of files so I was looking to find a way to narrow down my search to get exactly what I want.

The page has an image with the words new. When you click it a client side action executes. I say client side because monitoring with Fiddler does not show a server request.

Anyway a javascript function executes.

What I am trying to do is locate the script that executes. Using F12 developer tool I went to inspect the element that is clicked and...I stopped dead in my tracks.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Create" tabindex="0" class="ClassName">
    <img src="/_imgs/add_10.png" class="PictureClass">New</a>
```

How does javascript:void(0) execute a script? Perhaps I'm wrong and it is making a server postback??

Any pointers would be appreciated.

---

As an update all your pointers have been quite helpful but I still can't find the event that is being fired....but that is partially due to having to focus on a couple other issues.

One thing that has cause me difficulty is that there is a constantly running script so when I pause execution as @Hafthor states chrome dev tools put a blue modal over the page and I can't click any controls.

Comment: An event handler has been attached that fires on `click`. Which browser's dev tools?

Comment: Find any `EventListeners` for class, of `ClassName`, where as currently, `void(0)` 'ends' the default execution. This is simply currently preventing the execution of a *link*.

Comment: @Jon I have IE, Chrome, Firefox available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `void(0)` is a "do nothing" construct and the `javascript:` protocol should be avoided since it is recommended to use the click event handler and `return false` or cancel the event with `preventDefault`

The void means "return nothing" and if you do not do that in the javascript protocol, you run the risk that the call returns a value that is then shown in the page.

Example (that is served better with unobtrusive JS, but is shown as example)

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('somepage.html','_blank')">Click</a>
```

will pop a window if allowed but will render

```
[Object object]
```

in the page with the link.

```
<a href="javascript:void(window.open('somepage.html','_blank'))">Click</a>
```

will not since the void will suppress the return value of window.open and is in effect similar to

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('somepage.html','_blank'); return false">Click</a>
```

Again not recommended to have inline event handlers.

The script you saw execute could still be added externally to the link

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("ClassName")[0].onclick=function() {
    newImage();
  }
}
```

which would not be hindered by the void(0)

A better alternative could be

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("ClassName")[0].onclick=function() {
    newImage();
    return false; // now javascript:void(0) can be removed from the link
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A way I've used is from Safari or Chrome load the page, open the debugger, press pause, then click that 'Create' button and it should break at the first executed bit of JavaScript.

Comment: I tried that but there is some sort of a continously running script and pausing execution results in a blue modal overlay so I can't click a control. See above.